# Footprint connection for LED JK2835BWT-W

Tags: led, pcb-design

I need to use [this Cree LED](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/723/JSeries_2835_6V_18V_Consolidated-2940281.pdf) in a PCB design, but I have a question about it: what is the connection of the pads?

This component has a footprint with 4 pads:

[image: footprint_image].

This footprint is provided by the KiCad library, and matches with my LED producer's dimensions and number of pads.

When I make a schematic with it and I choose the typical diode symbol with 2 pins, and switch to designing the PCB it suggest connections for pin 1 and 2 (both left pins), but what happened with the other 2?

I don't know if pins 1 and 2 must be connected as well, or not, and I didn't find anything in the datasheet.

Can anyone who has worked with it help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *This component has a footprint with 4 pads*

This is the 2-pad arrangement recommended in the [Cree data sheet for your device](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/723/JSeries_2835_6V_18V_Consolidated-2940281.pdf): -

[image]

[image]